# How to prevent absolutely positioned img from moving

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, css-position

So I have a flexbox with some elements and over the flexbox, I want to put a foreground which should be absolutely positioned. What I am trying to achieve is, that with window resize, the foreground will change its size but not its position. Currently, when the window is small, the image is moving up.

```css
main div.heroBoxContainer {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  height: inherit;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
  align-items: center;
}

main div.heroBoxContainer .hGroup {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
}

div.heroBoxContainer h1.heroHeadline,
div.heroBoxContainer h1.heroHeadline {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0 0 0 10rem;
  transform: skew(-6deg) rotate(-6deg);
}

div.heroBoxContainer p.subHeadline {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin: 0rem 0 0 10rem;
  transform: skew(-6deg) rotate(-6deg);
}

div.heroBoxContainer p.priceHeadline {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin: 0rem 0 8rem 10rem;
  color: rgba(255, 220, 58, 1);
  transform: skew(-6deg) rotate(-6deg);
}

div img.heroForeground {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8vh;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 80%;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 15vw;
}

#carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 75vh;
  position: relative;
}

.slide-image {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 75vh;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section id="carousel">
  <div class="slide-image" id="slide1">
    <div class="heroBoxContainer">
      <img src="https://www.cheopstech.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/placeholder-3.png" class="heroForeground">
      <div class="hGroup">
        <h1 class="heroHeadline">LOREM IPSUM<br> DOLOR SIT AMET</h1>
        <p class="subHeadline">LOREM IPSUM:</p>
        <p class="priceHeadline">LOREM IPSUM</p>
        <a href="/" class="btnCta mobileGetReg triggerGetReg">LOREM IPSUM</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your absolutely positioned `img.heroForeground` has it's `top` set to `8vh` which will change as the window size changes during resize. This is leading to the unwanted shifting during window resize. Instead, center the element using `transform`/`translate`.

```css
div img.heroForeground {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  …
}
```

**Demo**

```css
main div.heroBoxContainer {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  height: inherit;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
  align-items: center;
}

main div.heroBoxContainer .hGroup {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
}

div.heroBoxContainer h1.heroHeadline,
div.heroBoxContainer h1.heroHeadline {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0 0 0 10rem;
  transform: skew(-6deg) rotate(-6deg);
}

div.heroBoxContainer p.subHeadline {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin: 0rem 0 0 10rem;
  transform: skew(-6deg) rotate(-6deg);
}

div.heroBoxContainer p.priceHeadline {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin: 0rem 0 8rem 10rem;
  color: rgba(255, 220, 58, 1);
  transform: skew(-6deg) rotate(-6deg);
}

div img.heroForeground {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 80%;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 75vh;
  position: relative;
}

.slide-image {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 75vh;
  background-position: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section id="carousel">
  <div class="slide-image" id="slide1">
    <div class="heroBoxContainer">
      <img src="https://www.cheopstech.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/placeholder-3.png" class="heroForeground">
      <div class="hGroup">
        <h1 class="heroHeadline">LOREM IPSUM<br> DOLOR SIT AMET</h1>
        <p class="subHeadline">LOREM IPSUM:</p>
        <p class="priceHeadline">LOREM IPSUM</p>
        <a href="/" class="btnCta mobileGetReg triggerGetReg">LOREM IPSUM</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ju5bsxw/)

Comment: Hey @Andy Hoffman, thanks for the answer! What is the reason of combining translate and position absolute with left and top please?

Comment: @TomášNosek We need `translate` to account for 1/2 of the image width and height. Removing `translate` would place the image *starting* at 50% top/left, not centered directly in the center of the screen. Play around in the inspector to see the result.